# What is the best JS & HTML5 code to support a touch gesture content carousel on the iPad?

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, extjs

Besides Sencha and jQueryMobile, what else is out there that is simple and small in size?

Answer (score 2):

You can give [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) a try.
It's a jquery-syntax-like js framework for mobile (developed by Thomas Fuchs)

Comment: I would recommend Zepto.js. It's aming to be the most lightweight JS-library for mobile, and it is pretty damn good.

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework named Wink toolkit developped to be very small in size compare to Sencha !
They now have a lot of functionnalaties.

Here is the home page of the project :
http://www.winktoolkit.org/

It's released under the simple BSD licence.

Answer (score 0):

jQTouch [http://jqtouch.com](http://jqtouch.com/). Small and usable!